# Nested classes in different files with inheritance

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, inner-classes, instance-variables

So I made a single program with one class containing a number of classes, but I thought it would be more organised to split it up into multiple programs, one for each subclass. Would this be a better way to organise my code, and does this affect performance or anything?

And how would I go about splitting this code into two files? The main program would have the Texty class, and I would need to somehow include the String class from another file, but you can't include classes in Ruby, so how would this be done whilst also keeping the inheritance from Texty? And how would I access the instance variable `@inst_var` from the other file?

```
class Texty
  def initialize
    @inst_var = 0
  end
  def texty_method
    puts 'Bar'
  end
  class String < Texty
    def output(string)
      puts string
    end
  end
end

Texty::String.new.output('Foo')
```

Comment: Nesting classes like that won't create any sort of relationship between Texty and String. You can pull the String class(I'd choose another name for this) into its own file, require Texty right before it's declaration and maintain the same result you're getting now.

Comment: Well... Not quite the same because you'd be referencing String outside of the Texty namespace, but I think you got the picture.

Comment: Would I still be able to access the instance variables in Texty this way? (From String)

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your code into multiple files and object will tax performance but by so little that you wont even notice.

If you're splitting program by the classes, my suggestion is to use the rails naming conventions.

`TestClass` -> `test_class.rb`

Then at the top of your main program do: `require_relative 'test_class.rb'`

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your files up like this, and see what happens.

In `texty/texty.rb`:

```
class Texty
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end
end
```

In `texty/string.rb`:

```
require_relative 'texty.rb'

class Texty
  class String < Texty
    def test
      puts @x
    end
  end
end
```

Then run from the command line:

```
$ ruby -r ./texty/string.rb -e "Texty::String.new(1).test"
```

It should print `1`, indicating that your `Texty::String` class inherited the initialization of the `@x` ivar from its parent class of `Texty`.